# drop down list in android

Tags: android, quickaction

Drop list using quick action dialog in android ?

drop down list should be

[image]

i don't want to use spinner.

i have tried out example

http://www.chupamobile.com/tutorial/details/63/Quick+Actions+-+Tutorial/

and

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

please help.

Thanks in advance......

Comment: so above dont help? what is your question here?

Comment: my question is how to add list view inside quick action  as quick action item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Shivaji,

This would not be possible with straight options and you need customize library for that if I am not wrong.  Because QuickAction is preferably used to offer a minimum set of actions.

However, as an alternate, I would suggest you to make use of [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) and integrate your ListView inside.

This should work perfectly for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this open source project ("a small android library to create QuickAction dialog with Gallery3D app style")

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PopUpwindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) here.Popup window method showAtLocation(View yourEditTExt, int gravity, int x, int y) will show dropdown list below EditText